# Swift Error handling with HTML scraping

Tags: html, xcode, swift3, error-handling, wkwebview

I'm trying to throw an error if the scraping and parsing process of a WebPage (which is loaded after username and password login) fails but I can't solve the problem.

Here is what I tried:

```
enum HTMLError: Error { //HTML Error Handler
    case badInnerHTML
}

struct GeneralitiesResponse {


    init(_ innerHTML: Any?) throws {
        guard let htmlString = innerHTML as? String else { throw
            HTMLError.badInnerHTML
        }
        let doc = try SwiftSoup.parse(htmlString)
        let names = try doc.getElementsByClass("name").array()
        let codes = try doc.getElementsByClass("usrname font_size_11 open_sans_condensed_bold").array()
        let schools = try doc.getElementsByClass("scuola").array()

        for i in 0..<names.count {
            let name = try names[i].text()
            let code = try codes[i].text()
            let school = try schools[i].text()

            print(name)
            print(code)
            print(school)
            print("")
            // Setting UserDeafults for user data
            Defaults[.username] = name
            Defaults[.code] = code
            Defaults[.school] = school

        }

    }

}
```

Then I use `do-catch` block to see if there is an error:

```
func takeHTML() {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML") { (innerHTML, error) in
        do {
            let response = try GeneralitiesResponse(innerHTML)
            print("Got Generalities Response")
        } catch let error {
            print("Something went wrong: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

If I use the correct credentials everything is ok and "Got generalities response" is printed in the console. However, if I use the wrong credentials the page that needs to be scraped is not loaded and scraped and so it should print "Something went wrong..." but it doesn't.